# Can I get automatic HTML escape in Padrino?

Tags: padrino

Rails 3+ has automatic XSS prevention. Can I get the same thing in Padrino, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you are using Slim for example is turned on by default

```
== 'this is not escaped'
= 'this is escaped'
```

Comment: What about erubis? I do it as sinatra FAQ page:  `Sinatra::Base.set :erubis, :escape_html => true`, but it does't work for padrino.